# Handle common variables inside the controller

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, aura-framework

I am very new to Salesforce. I am using some variables which is common in multuple methods inside this controller. Is there a way to define the variables once and reuse them inside this component methods?

**controller**

```
doInit : function(cmp, event, helper) {
   var categoryUsed = 'Abc';
   var locations = ['ten', 'twenty', 'thirty'];
   var address = window.location.search;
   //other logic1
},
handleFlag : function(cmp, event, helper) {
   var categoryUsed = 'Abc';
   var locations = ['ten', 'twenty', 'thirty'];
   var address = window.location.search;
   //other logic2
},
handleArea : function(cmp, event, helper) {
   var categoryUsed = 'Abc';
   var locations = ['ten', 'twenty', 'thirty'];
   var address = window.location.search;
   //other logic3
}
```

Is there a way to declare these common variables (categoryUsed, locations,address) once and use in all the above methods inside this component?

Answer (score 1):

In an Aura component like this one, your persistent or shared storage should be in *component attributes*.

An alternate approach is to factor common code that uses constant values and shared logic, rather than or in addition to shared state as such, into the helper object to reduce code duplication.

Aura is an obsolete framework. While there are still a handful of places where Aura is required, if your use case permits, consider using Lightning Web Components instead. LWC allows you to structure your component using more mainstream, easy-to-understand structures, including modules and classes with instance variables.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. +10